# Prove $\{x: x\notin x\}$ does not exist

Tags: solution-verification, set-theory

I'm trying to prove the statement without the notion of [class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(set_theory)). So in the formal language of the Zermelo-Fraenkel axiom I believe we are to stablish $\neg \big[\exists A: \forall x: (x\in A\iff x\notin x)\big]$, i.e, $$\forall A: \exists x: \neg(x\in A\iff x\notin x)\tag{$\alpha$}$$

***Proof**.* Let $A$ be an arbitrary set. Choose $x=A$ so then $\neg(A\in A\iff A\notin A)$. Thus, $\alpha$ must be true.

**Question:** Is this proof alright?

Comment: Did you prove that $A\notin A$ for all $A$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila No.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of manipulating the formal statement, you need to first understand what you're trying to show.

For any given set $A$, we need to find some $x$ such that $x\notin x$ if and only if $x\notin A$. This is the negation of the internal $\leftrightarrow$.

So in order to do that, you need to either find an element of $A$ which is a member of itself, or find a set which is not a member of $A$ that is not an element of itself.

The first type, of course, is harder, since clearly some sets do not have such members. For example, $\varnothing$ and $\{\varnothing\}$ and $\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}$ and $\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\},\{\{\varnothing\}\},\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}\}$, and so many more others. So perhaps a more reasonable approach is to just try and show that there is always some $x\notin A$ such that $x\notin x$.

Now. You proposed to take $x=A$, but if you haven't proved that $A\notin A$ holds for all sets in $\sf ZF$, then your proof is fundamentally incomplete.

The idea, instead, is to use the Separation/Specification/Subset/Bounded comprehension schema (which truly goes by many names), and apply $x\notin x$ to $A$ itself. Namely, consider the set $B=\{x\in A\mid x\notin x\}$, and conclude that $B\notin A$ and that $B\notin B$ either, since $B\subseteq A$. This simply repeats the standard proof of the Russell's paradox to produce a theorem: for any given set $A$, there is a subset of $A$ which is not a member of $A$ (and consequently also not a member of itself).

Once you've proved that $A\notin A$ holds for all sets, assuming $\sf ZF$, then we actually get that this $B$ mentioned above is in fact $A$ itself. But the whole thing will work also in $\sf ZF-Reg$, and in even weaker theories than that. Even for sets which do contain themselves, or have members which do contain themselves.

Comment: How about this? If we are to prove $\forall A: \exists x: x\notin A\iff x\notin x$ we've to prove two things. One is proving $\forall A: \exists x: x\notin A \implies x\notin x$. If we choose $x=\emptyset$ this a trivially true. Secondly, we need to stablish $\forall A: \exists x: x\notin x\implies x\notin A$. By way of contradiction assume there is $A$ such that for all $x$ we have $x\notin x$ and $x\in A$. So in particular we'll have that $A\notin A$ and $A\in A$ a contradiction.

Comment: No, that's not what you need to show. You need to show that there is an $x$ for which *the equivalence* holds.

Comment: I don't get it.

Comment: You need to prove that $\exists x(p(x)\leftrightarrow q(x))$. Showing that there is one $x$ for which the one implication holds and another for which the other implication holds does not mean that you've shown that there is an $x$ for which *the biconditional* holds.

Comment: So, let me try something different. I'll show that $\neg \big[\exists A: \forall x: (x\in A \iff x\notin x)\big]$. As a argument by contradiction if $\exists A: \forall x: x\in A\iff x\notin x$. We'll have that for such a set A it holds $(A\in A\iff A\notin A)$, a contradiction.

Comment: Yes, that is also fine. That *is* the formalisation of the Russell paradox. The original way you were trodding hinted that you might be happier with the actual suggestion in my answer, which is a slightly more general theorem. Nevertheless, yes, proving the Russell paradox *is* what you're supposed to do here.

Comment: Finally. Haven't read about that paradox but I will.

Comment: Quick question... Do do you mean by "That is ALSO fine", was one of my aforementioned direct attempts successful?

Answer (score 0):

This statement is just an alternate form of Berry's paradox. And the proof seems correct. The way I would approach this is:

If there does exist some set $A := \{B: B \notin B\}$, then $A \in A \iff A \notin A$. We know that assuming $A$ to exist causes a contradiction ($x \iff \neg x$ will never hold), so $A$ must not exist. $\square$

Or, an even simpler method to prove is that, if you work in ZFC, then the axiom of regularity already implies that such a set $A$ does not exist (since $A \cap \{A\} = \varnothing$).