# Alternative prove for $\forall A: A\notin A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I've seen this theorem is proven [*axiom of regularity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity) but I'm trying to produce a proof without this axiom's help.

*My attempt:* Let $A$ be an arbitrary set. By the [*axiom of specification*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification), there exists the set $$S:=\{x\in A: A\notin A\}$$Firstly, we observe $A\notin S$ because otherwise we'll have $A\in A$ and $A\notin A$. So in $A$ being arbitrarily chosen, by the [*uniqueness of the empty set*](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Empty_Set_is_Unique) we know $S=\emptyset$.

Now, we'll stablish that $A\notin A$ by cases.

*Case $i)$* If $A=\emptyset$ then cleary $A\notin A$.

*Case $ii)$* Assume $A\ne \emptyset$. Since $S=\emptyset$ we have
\begin{align*}
\neg \big[\exists y: y\in A\wedge A\notin A\big]&\iff \forall y: (y\notin A\vee A\in A)\\
&\iff (\forall y: y\notin A)\vee A\in A\tag{since  $A\in A$ isn't free in $y$}
\end{align*}
But by virtue of the [*uniqueness of the empty set*](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Empty_Set_is_Unique) whenever for all $y$, $y\notin A$ we get $A=\emptyset$, a contradiction. So $\neg (\forall y: y\notin A)$ then $A\in A$ for all $A$. Hence, in particular we'll get $\emptyset\in \emptyset$.  In a nutshell, it's not possible that $A\ne \emptyset$.

Given that in the only possible case the statement is true we conclude $\forall A: A\notin A$.

Comment: Just $2$ hours ago, [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4402240/is-my-proof-that-forall-x-x-notin-x-correct) came up. See also your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4394280/prove-x-x-notin-x-does-not-exist).

Comment: In fact, there is no proof of $\forall x(x\not\in x)$ that doesn't use regularity: it is consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC-Reg}$ that there are self-containing sets (assuming $\mathsf{ZFC}$ itself is consistent in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

You correctly conclude that $A \not \in S$. (Because if $A \in S$, then $A \not \in A$. But then also $S = A$, so $A \in A$, giving a contradiction). However, the next step is wrong: "So in $A$ being arbitrarily chosen, by the uniqueness of the empty set we know $S = \emptyset$."

Either $S = \emptyset$ (if $A \in A$) or $S = A$ (if $A \not\in A$).

Comment: Why can I not conclude $S=\emptyset$?

Comment: What argument do you have? But note that your argument is already wrong for an $A$ that does _not_ satisfy $A \in A$. E.g., if $A = \{1\}$, then $S = \{1\} \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: My argument is: Since $A$ is arbitrary and $A\notin S$. This means: $\forall A: \neg(A\in S)$. But, it can be proven that the only that set $B$ such that $\neg (x\in B)$ for all $x$ is the empty set ($B=\emptyset$). Because of this uniqueness we'll get $S=\emptyset$.

Comment: Where does the $\forall A$ come from? Your $S$ depends on $A$!